# How to change a wlan0 mac address?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wireless

I bought the Miniature WiFi Module from ADAFruit (http://www.adafruit.com/products/814) and was wondering if it is possible to change the MAC address associated with it. I have tried using the following code:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0

sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55

sudo ifup wlan0
```

or

```
sudo ifdown wlan0

sudo macchanger -r wlan0

sudo ifup wlan0
```

or by adding a line in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
hwaddress ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

When using `lsusb` the device shows up as "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter". In `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, `driver=rtl1871xdrv`. I am running ISC DHCP Server.

The device works otherwise. I just want to be able to change the MAC address

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, please, choose another section of StackExchange for this type of inquiry.

Comment: ah, sorry. Was using Raspbian so looked like a good place to put it. I will find another location.

Comment: Some drivers require the device to be up to do that. Try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up ; sudo macchanger -r wlan0`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. It has the error "Can't read permanent MAC: Operation not supported. Even though there is output for the NEW MAC, ifconfig shows the old MAC address.

Answer (score 7):

For "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" (cat /etc/os-release), "Raspberry Pi reference 2017-06-21" (cat /etc/rpi-issue) (maybe also 2017-07-05) (thanks @Heinrich Ulbricht) and earlier see [my answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63509/58211).

For "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" (cat /etc/os-release), "Raspberry Pi reference 2017-08-16" (cat /etc/rpi-issue) (maybe also 2017-07-05) and later things changed. For example `eth0` is now listed by [systemd’s predictable network interface name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) `enxb827ebxxxxxx`. So my previous method via `if-pre-up.d` stopped working.

Instead you can use `systemd` and create the file `/etc/systemd/network/00-mac.link` as explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing#Method_1:_systemd-networkd):

```
[Match]
OriginalName=wlan0

[Link]
MACAddress=b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx
NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path
```

Comment: Confirmed working with Raspian Stretch Lite. Kudos, Frank.

Comment: Confirming, too, that it works with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.

Comment: I just did the second one on Buster and it worked.  Cheap Chinese Ethernet adapters came with the same MAC address.  ~$1.20 for 3x USB and Ethernet though, can't complain too much.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - most of the standard ways of doing this didnt seem to work on the raspberry.

My situation was a bit different - I have a Raspberry PI B where the ethernet chip has died and so I used a usb-ethernet adpater. The adapter is maybe not the highest quality as it didnt have a unique MAC address. The adapter is assigned to `eth1`

I found the answer by enzorik here... http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5486, worked for me. Essentially...

Create a new script:
`sudo nano /etc/init.d/mac.sh`

Paste into this script (settign your MAC address as required) ...

```
#! /bin/sh
ifconfig eth1 down hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
ifconfig eth1 up
```

Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mac.sh`

Then run: `sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/mac.sh defaults`

Comment: I would suggest to rather save mac.sh in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/. This will avoid the usage of `update-rc.d`. See my answer below.

Comment: I ran into this same issue.  I'm gonna try this.  But the forum link you refer to is no longer good.

Answer (score 2):

For "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" (cat /etc/os-release), "Raspberry Pi reference 2017-08-16" (cat /etc/rpi-issue) (maybe also 2017-07-05) and later see [my answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71483/58211).

For "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" (cat /etc/os-release), "Raspberry Pi reference 2017-06-21" (cat /etc/rpi-issue) (thanks @Heinrich Ulbricht) (maybe also 2017-07-05) and earlier

you can add the following script to `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/mac`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = wlan0 ]; then
    ip link set dev "$IFACE" address b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx
fi
```

and make it executable with

```
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/mac
```

This should work with systemd and be more robust than the older `update-rc.d` method.

Comment: Tested successfully with "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" (`cat /etc/os-release`), "Raspberry Pi reference 2017-06-21" (`cat /etc/rpi-issue`). (I'm documenting this to narrow down the release frame it works for since your second answer suggests it stops working at some point.)

Comment: Note this method will not work on Raspian Stretch. Thankfully Frank added a second answer and both are still technically correct.

Comment: I just did the linked answer on Buster and it worked.  Cheap Chinese Ethernet adapters came with the same MAC address.  ~$1.20 for 3x USB and Ethernet though, can't complain too much.

Answer (score 1):

**it is possible** to change your mac address but this is a feature of the hardware and drivers.

i was successful using two wifi adapters **TL-WN722N** and the **Alfa AWUS036H**

however you should be aware that the Alfa AWUS036H has to be powered through a powered usb hub.  if you try and run it directly off the pi you will get kernel panics.

```
service ifplugd stop

service wicd stop

ifconfig wlan0 down

macchanger -r wlan0 

ifconfig wlan0 up
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

For the 8192cu driver you could do this by creating the file `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf`  (the filename does not matter but it should have `.conf` extension) and adding a line that looks like:

```
options 8192cu rtw_initmac="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
```

where "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" is the static MAC address

Comment: I have this exact same Model RTL8188CUS and this is the only solution that worked. Thank you!